# stripe - create customer using email from checkout page

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

hi im just trying out stripe and i've run into an issue, im trying to create a new customer with the email provided from the form (im using the embedded checkout) but im not able to retrieve the email value to send with the newly created customer. its always empty. any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance!

Form:

```
<form action="/payment" method="POST">
              <script
                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="pk_test_---------------------"
                data-amount="15000"
                data-name="WetWired"
                data-description="Widget"
                data-billing-address="true"
                data-zip-code="true"
                data-shipping-address="true"
                data-locale="auto">
              </script>
            </form>
```

Node

```
app.post('/payment', function (req, res) {

 console.log("posted");

 // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
 var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
 var email = req.body.email;

 stripe.customers.create({
   source: token,
   plan:"tv_subscription",
   email : email
 }).then(function(customer) {
   return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 15000, // Amount in cents
    currency: "cad",
    description: 'android box',
    customer: customer.id
    });
 }).then(function(charge) {
 // YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later!

  });
 });
```

Comment: Instead of `email` you're probably looking for `stripeEmail`? https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-parameters

Comment: @Adamjstevenson that's exactly it! duh lol thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 0):

Stripe requires the email address to be filled out by the customer, when you process the payment on your server, stripe will provide you with your customers email address.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#required

You can even fill out the customers email for them if you know it in advance, but assuming you don't, you either need a listener for when they enter text into that email field or go about it the right way by extracting it from stripe upon successful completion of the charge.